# Laravel Blade simple foreach including $loop->first

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I have a form where I display four text field inputs. The current `app()->getLocale()` input is displayed on the left, and the below code is for the remaining 3 locales which are displayed on the right:

```
@foreach(['ca','en','es','nl'] as $lang)

    @if(app()->getLocale() == $lang) @continue @endif

    <li>
        <a href="#{{ $lang }}" class="@if($loop->first) active @endif"
    </li>

@endforeach
```

These are all menu tabs that are hidden, only the first one should be displayed as active, hence:

```
@if($loop->first) active @endif
```

The problem however is, that when the current locale is `ca`, also the `$loop->first()` will be `ca`. And this one cannot be the active one, since it will never be displayed on the right side.

I am trying to find an easy fix without too many `if else` things. Also, the array `['ca','en','es','nl']` will be changed for some data that comes from the `config`, so there will be more locales later and `ca` will not always be the first one. So I cannot do checks with `@if(app()->getLocale() == 'ca')` since that will change in the future as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
['ca','en','es','nl']
```

with:

```
array_diff(['ca','en','es','nl'], [app()->getLocale()])
```

and remove this:

```
@if(app()->getLocale() == $lang) @continue @endif
```

This will remove the item representing the current language from your array.

Comment: @Hardist Ok, so you want to learn something new? You can use `@class(['active' => $loop->first])` instead of `class="@if($loop->first) active @endif"`. It's definitely more convenient and easy when you want to add more than one situation this way :)